# NSFetchRequestResult returns duplicate data from the database

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a simple entity with `identifier` (constraint) and `name` fields. In `ViewController` I try to add data to the database without worrying about duplicates and there really is no duplicate data in the database, but when I try to get records, I get twice as many of them. As I found out, this only happens when I try to write something to the database, and regardless of whether the attempt was successful, the data goes to my `NSFetchRequestResult`. What is the reason for this behavior?

DB content now:

[image]

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //if comment this loop I won't get duplicates
        for i in 0...5 {
            let ent = Entity(context: moc)
            ent.identifier = Int16(i)
            ent.name = "Username"
            try? moc.save() //if the code is not executed for the first time, then the attempt is unsuccessful due to identifier constraint
        }
        
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")
        let fetchedEntities = try? moc.fetch(fetch) as? [Entity]
        print(fetchedEntities!.count) // Output: 12 (actually only 6 records in the db)
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have 6 records and then you add 6 more and you are surprised you get 12 back from the fetch request? Tell me I am missing something...

Comment: 6 records are not added to the database because records with this `identifier` field value already exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code where you create the objects to

```
for i in 0...5 {
    let ent = Entity(context: moc)
    ent.identifier = Int16(i)
    ent.name = "Username"
}
do {
    try moc.save() 
} catch {
     moc.reset()
}
```

This way you will remove the faulty (duplicate) objects from the context